# rake aborted! PG::ConnectionBad: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I can't do rake db:migrate.

I've tried to change in `pg_hba.conf` md5 -> trust, but it's not helped me, because I get new error with trust:

```
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: ▒▒▒▒▒:  ▒▒▒▒ "roman" ▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
```

I don't know what it means. 
I try to create simple app on ruby on rails with postgresql server (pgAdmin4, postgresql11, latest version of rails and ruby) on windows 10.

My database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  username: simpleblog
  password: <%= ENV['SIMPLEBLOG_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: simpleblog_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: simpleblog_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: simpleblog_production
```

My pg_hba.conf

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32           md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                md5
```

So i get... first

```
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

then when I changed md5 -> trust

```
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: ▒▒▒▒▒:  ▒▒▒▒ "roman" ▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
```

Comment: You showed the pg_hba.conf before setting it to trust, but not after. Show the after version as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the "SIMPLEBLOG_DATABASE_PASSWORD=something" inside the application.yml